# how not to load any images using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to navigate through pages as a mobile user. I used this starter code:

```js
import Puppeteer from 'puppeteer'; // Using ES6 Module

(async () => {
    const iPhone = Puppeteer.devices['iPhone 11 Pro Max'];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 90,
        defaultViewport: iPhone.viewport
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.emulate(iPhone);

    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");
    await page.tap('input[type="search"]');
    await page.type('input[type="search"]', "boats");
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.tap('a[data-hveid="CAMQAQ"]');
})();
```

**Note**: This code might not navigate in your browser because the selector for images isn't the best. This is only a temp code.

This code runs fine, but I wanted to reduce internet usage by not loading these images.
How can I negate any image, video, or anything that might be heavy on loading the page?

Comment: An example: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/examples/block-images.js

Comment: Yes this is a perfect example and almost is the solution except it only negates the images for the first page loaded, afterwards, all images are loaded.